# How to sense multiple files using Airflow FileSensor?

Tags: python, airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am creating a dag. I am trying to sense multiple files from my local folder but not able to sense all files present in the folder. what should be the correct logic?

```
sensing_task=FileSensor(task_id='senseFile',
                        filepath='dags/source/*.csv',
                        poke_interval=10,
                        fs_conn_id='fs_my_conn')
```

while executing it is actually searching for "*.csv" file and not the pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you probably need to define your own sensor. Looking at the [source code for filesensor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.12/_modules/airflow/contrib/sensors/file_sensor.html), you could probably do something like this to implement globbing.

```
class GlobSensor(BaseSensorOperator):
    template_fields = ('filepath',)
    ui_color = '#91818a'

    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, filepath, fs_conn_id='fs_default', *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.fs_conn_id = fs_conn_id

    def poke(self, context):
        hook = FSHook(self.fs_conn_id)
        basepath = hook.get_path()
        full_path = os.path.join(basepath, self.filepath)
        self.log.info('Poking for glob %s', full_path)
        return len(glob.glob(full_path)) > 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what pattern you are referring to in your comment:
"it is actually searching for "*.csv" file and not the pattern."

The filepath is set to search for "*.csv"
filepath='dags/source/*.csv'

I had the same requirement. My solution was to use the FileSensor as you did, and then create a 2nd task using the BashOperator to run a bash script to process 1 or more files. I used a for loop to process all new files and then a case stmt to perform the logic associated with each filename pattern.